# How to pick only one type from list?

Tags: typescript

There is single interface `IStorage` where every key has two types:

```js
interface IStorage {
    key: boolean | CustomStore<boolean>,
    key2: number | CustomStore<number>
}

type CustomStore<T> = {
    value: T,
    init: (value: T) => void;
    set: (value: T) => void;
}
```

The class `LiveStorage` have `defaultStorage` (first type of `IStorage`) and `storage` (second):

```js
class LiveStorage<D = { [key: string]: any }, S = { [key: string]: CustomStore<any> }> {

    private defaultStorage: D
    storage: S

    constructor(defaultStorage: D) {
        this.defaultStorage = defaultStorage as D
        this.storage = {} as S
    }
}
```

When create instance, `key` has both types:

```
let liveStorage = new LiveStorage<IStorage, IStorage>({})
liveStorage.storage.key // boolean | CustomStore<boolean>
```

Are there ways to `key` will have only `CustomStore<boolean>` by default? With single interface and without `(liveStorage.storage.key as CustomStore<boolean>)`. I know that is only compile time, just want to get suggestion from IDE without `(x as type)` every time.

Comment: what typescript version you are using?

Comment: @AshotAleqsanyan typescript 5.1.6, vs code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially you want `defaultStorage` to be of a "base" key-value type, and then you want `storage` to be a *transformed* version of that type.  For each property key `K` of the base type `T`, you want to take the property value type `T[K]` and map it to `CustomStore<T[K]>`.  So we can define a **[mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html)** that does this:

```
type CustomStorageFor<T> =
    { [K in keyof T]: CustomStore<T[K]> };
```

For your example then, you wouldn't want to use your `IStorage` type directly, with [unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of base and mapped properties.  Instead, you would define `IStorage` to be the base type

```
interface IStorage {
    key: boolean
    key2: number
}
```

And then you get the `CustomStorage` version by mapping it:

```
type CustomStorageForIStorage = CustomStorageFor<IStorage>;
/* type CustomStorageForIStorage = {
    key: CustomStore<boolean>;
    key2: CustomStore<number>;
} */
```

---

Now your `LiveStorage` class can be [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in just the base type `T`, and `storage` will be given type `CustomStorageFor<T>`:

```
class LiveStorage<T extends object> {

    private defaultStorage: T
    storage: CustomStorageFor<T>;

    constructor(defaultStorage: T) {
        this.defaultStorage = defaultStorage
        this.storage = {} as CustomStorageFor<T>; // you need to implement this
    }
}
```

Now when you call the `LiveStorage` constructor, the compiler will infer the type argument `T` to be that of the constructor argument (and I've [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) `T` to [the `object` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-2.html#object-type) so that you'll get an error if you try to pass in a `string` or something):

```
const defaultStorage: IStorage = { key: true, key2: 1 };
let liveStorage = new LiveStorage(defaultStorage);
// let liveStorage: LiveStorage<IStorage>
liveStorage.storage.key // CustomStore<boolean>
```

In fact you don't even need the `IStorage` type if you don't want to give it a name; the compiler will happily synthesize an equivalent object type from the constructor argument:

```
let liveStorage = new LiveStorage({ key: true, key2: 1 });
// let liveStorage: LiveStorage<{ key: boolean; key2: number; }>
liveStorage.storage.key // CustomStore<boolean>
```

Either way will work.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-3q5yq0jWbg6+FGs1Wu0nd1ev1BlgnSZCDQi6OzmqzVU1XVna7xrani8Z+9zDHBcLw-qZcPLlUFhP6g2WM351AO1lzAONyW7QsFYjv+5qSgyWp3na3aUH2v5Dna7AIpudrrKya5-qy25bvufZHo8eCnm8a6UEAA)

Comment: How to modify `CustomStorageFor` in order to fix error `Type 'string' cannot be used to index type 'CustomStorageFor<T>'`. It occurs when I try init `this.storage[key] = this.createStore(key)`

Comment: Looks like you have a followup question; you should consider posting a new question if you can't figure it out.  Comments sections on existing questions aren't great places to explore followups; at a minimum I need to see a [mre] (e.g., where is `key` coming from) and that really belongs in a real question post.  Also it's quite possible that the followup issue isn't really directly related to this one, and is just the next thing you ran into.  I'd guess you have a `for`...`in` or `Object.keys()` related typing question and that's not really relevant to mapped types.

Comment: I couldn't fix, added new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76894829/how-to-fix-error-with-index-by-string-for-mapped-type)